# AspectJ/Jetty/Java-8: error scanning entry UpdateParserFiles.class

Tags: intellij-idea, java-8, jetty, aop, aspectj

I am using aspectj (NOT in the sprint framework)

I get the following error at runtime when using jetty 9.4

`Error scanning entry org/aspectj/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/parser/UpdateParserFiles.class
from jar file:///C:/Users/<<user>>/IdeaProjects//<<my_app>>/<<my_module>>/build/libs/exploded/<<my_module>>.war/WEB-INF/lib/aspectjtools-1.8.13.jar`

The gradle deps in my project are:

```
compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjrt', version: '1.8.13'
compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjtools', version: '1.8.13'
```

When I change my gradle deps to:

```
compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjrt', version: '1.8.13'
compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver', version: '1.8.13'
```

the logging does not happen (i.e. the calling code is not intercepted)

My code snippet:

```
@Aspect
public class LoggerAspect {
  private static org.slf4j.Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerAspect.class);

  @Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(LogStats)")
  public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Object result = point.proceed();
    log.info(
        "#%s(%s): %s in %[msec]s",
        MethodSignature.class.cast(point.getSignature()).getMethod().getName(),
        point.getArgs(),
        result,
        System.currentTimeMillis() - start
    );
    return result;
  }
}



@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface LogStats {

}
```

Any thoughts on what could be causing this runtime exception OR not causing the aspectj code to invoke at all?

*EDIT*

full log trace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry org/aspectj/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/parser/UpdateParserFiles.class from jar file:///C:/Users/ramchandanil/IdeaProjects/webcnh_aop/cnhmaster/build/libs/exploded/cnhmaster.war/WEB-INF/lib/aspectjtools-1.8.13.jar
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.lambda$parseJar$0(AnnotationParser.java:880)
    at java.util.TreeMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(TreeMap.java:2897)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:872)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:836)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:471)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:680)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:230)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:158)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:146)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:932)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:917)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.lambda$parseJar$0(AnnotationParser.java:876)
    at java.util.TreeMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(TreeMap.java:2897)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:872)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:836)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:471)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:680)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: There should be [an exception](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.12.v20180830/jetty-annotations/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/annotations/AnnotationParser.java#L880) detailing why it failed, what does it say?

Comment: just added the stack trace

Comment: Make sure you have only 1 `asm.jar` and that its version 6.1 or newer.

Comment: The failure could occur due to many types of problems in your build or runtime environment. A full [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), either here or on GitHub, would be good. I need to reproduce the problem in order to help you solve it.

Comment: I'm surprised to see that aspectj distributes `UpdateParserFiles.class`. This class - originally from JDT - is intended only for build-time use (actually: build time of the compiler itself!). You may want to extract it from its jar and try if `javap` tells you more about the class file.